# Add vertical spacing between 'Hello' and 'World'

Tags: spacing

How to add vertical space between 'hello' and 'world' in this document? If I add `\\` between 'hello' and 'world' or add `\vspace{1cm}`, it cannot add vertical space.

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper,twoside,12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,paperheight=33cm,paperwidth=23cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newcommand\SUPERHUGE{\fontsize{130}{240}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
    \onehalfspacing
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{\SUPERHUGE{HELLO WORLD}}
    \end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

The result is
[image]
and I want to change it as below.
[image]

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: `\SUPERHUGE` is not a macro that accepts an argument. So if you use `\SUPERHUGE \textbf{HELLO WORLD}` it becomes better but with `\onehalfspacing` you get too much vertical distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your code to:

```
    \SUPERHUGE{\textbf{HELLO WORLD}\par}
```

This will fix the issue...

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want the space is smaller. How to reduce the spacing of ```\par```?

Comment: Just change your code `\newcommand\SUPERHUGE{\fontsize{130}{134}\selectfont}`

Comment: \SUPERHUGE does not take an argument

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I asked him to modify the `\baselineskip` or `leading` what he gave in that tag...

Comment: but why are you showing the use as `\SUPERHUGE{.....}` rather than ``\SUPERHUGE ..... ` the extra group is just misleading.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper,twoside,12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,paperheight=33cm,paperwidth=23cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newcommand\SUPERHUGE{\fontsize{130}{240}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
%    \onehalfspacing
%    \pagestyle{empty}
%    \vspace*{\fill}

        \centering\textbf{\SUPERHUGE{HELLO}}\par \vspace*{1cm}
         \centering\textbf{\SUPERHUGE{WORLD}}
  % \vspace*{\fill}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: \SUPERHUGE does not take an argument so you are preventing the correct linespacing with the extra groups. the font size and centering only need to be specified once